# Internal Server Error when running running yajra datatable using php artisan serve

Tags: yajra-datatable

I'm new in Laravel and I would like to ask for guidance for the datatables tutorial.

I tried to follow the laravel datatables tutorial from the link I provided below and I kept on encountering the issue below.
**Laravel Datatables Link:** 
https://appdividend.com/2018/04/16/laravel-datatables-tutorial-with-example/

**DataTables warning: table id=table – Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7**

I tried to change the providers and aliases from the config as instructed. I also went to the Web Developer > Network by clicking ctrl+shift+E in firefox, I went to xhr and I saw that its returning 500 Internal Server Error. Could you please guide me on how to fix this.

I am using php artisan serve to run the web page as instructed on the tutorial but according to the github link the artisan serve should be avoided.
github link: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables

Comment: don't use php artisan serve then. Try to use homestead, docker or one of the old wamp/xampp applications. An internal server error comes up in the server log. On your PC most likely in the event viewer, but as the page suggests: don't use it

Comment: change table id in both html and js and try again, and let me know what exact error you are getting in your browser>network section?